# How to format a date to "MM/dd"

Tags: sql

So I currently have a field that is outputting dates as

03/26/14

This is a weird question, but is there anyway where I can have the date output without the year?

I would like the date to look like

03/26

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using SQL Server, you could:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 101)
```

Comment: Hmm this one is outputting 03/2014...I do not want the year, just the month and day....but I figured it out with your suggestion using LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),101),5). Thanks!

Comment: @user3348557, I've updated to a better method.  I didn't read the question correctly.  What I have there now will output 03/31

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 03)
```